# How to write xpath for the on/off button present in a table for which class is compound class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

This element can be turned off or on. As the class is compound class, not sure how to write the xpath. So wrote like this

```
//tr[1]/td[4]/div[1]/div/div/div[@css='div.ios-switch.on']
```

Screen shots are attached here
[image: when turned off]

[image: When turned of]

Can you help me in writing the xpath for this element

Comment: You can right click on the element in inspector and select copy xpath

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead - `//tr[1]/td[4]/div[1]/div/div/div[@class='ios-switch on']`

Comment: this will not work because the class name has space in it. error **selenium.InvalidSelectorException** is noticed. If i replace space with dot, no element is thrown.

Comment: Try css selector instead of xpath -- div.ios-switch.on

Comment: used css like `//tr[1]/td[4]/div[1]/div/div/div[@css='div.ios-switch.on']` , exception is element not present. When tried to get the class name and match, selenium is getting only **ios-switch** but not completely like **ios-switch off** This page can contain multille elements of the same class. If the page has only one element, i could directly used **css='div.ios-switch.on'**

Answer (score 0):

```
"#checkbox1011 [class^='ios-switch']"
or
"#checkbox1011 .ios-switch.on,.ios-switch.off"
```

Try using these CSS selectors.

Comment: `checkbox1011` this si dymanic. so can't include in the identifier

Answer (score 0):

For the above screenshot, let me assume the username as `sabrina galloway`.

The toggle switch should present in the same row of username column.

You can use xpath like,

```
.//tr[./descendant::td[contains(.,'sabrina galloy')]/descendant::*[contains(@class,'ios-switch')]/div[@class='handle']
```

Comment: there are multiple elements of the same class. i.e there are multiple switches. I need to use xpath or xpath in combination with css. Can you update the answer.

Comment: From the screenshot, i can guess that there is a list of users on the page and for each user, there is a corresponding toggle switch available. am I right?

Comment: Again, sabrina galloway, this is input given while executing the test. Can we make concatenate two webelements for an element which sits in table

Answer (score 0):

```
//div[@id='checkbox1011']//td[@class='ios-switch-on']
```

Comment: //div[@id='checkbox1011'], id here is dynamic. for `class = "ios-switch on"` , will it work if i write like `ios-switch-on`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
//tr[1]/td[4]/div[1]/div/div/div[@css='.ios-switch.on' or '.ios-switch.off']
```

Hopefully this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use //div[starts-with(@class,'ios-switch')]

Comment: there are four elements of same type in the same table. I need to know the class name exactly i.e ios-switch on to know whether button is turned on or off. if it's only one element present, that would have been easy :)